# Can't hide column in jquery datatable shows TypeError: table.column is not a function

Tags: datatables

I am using jQuery datatables to show grid view of my records.

I took the reference of column show/hide api from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html).

As defined I am trying to use it in my project with all CSS & JS files.

When I run this it shows me error as:

```
TypeError: table.column is not a function
```

My jquery is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('.dataTables-example').dataTable({"scrollX": true});

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column') );

    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
} );
});
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling datatables 1.9 or previous in this line:

`var table = $('.dataTables-example').dataTable({"scrollX": true});`

Change this to:

`var table = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({"scrollX": true});`

notice the capital `D` in `DataTable`. You need that to be able to call datatables 1.10+ and use its functions like `column(DT)` which doesn't exist in previous versions.

See this for example: https://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to change this too for datatable v1.10.0+ version:

```
var column = table.api().column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are struggling with a similar type of problem in datatable version **1.9.*** can do

```
// column
    var ColNum = $(this).attr('data-column');

    // Define
    var bVis = table.fnSettings().aoColumns[ColNum].bVisible;

    // Toggle
    table.fnSetColumnVis(ColNum, bVis ? false : true);
```

instead of

```
var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column') );

column.visible( ! column.visible() );
```